# nm's uninitialized data section

Tags: g++

I'm trying to learn the details behind how the compiler works and I was wondering what the symbol B means when using nm.  I tried to follow std::cout into libstdc++, but it ends with

```
nm -DC /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep cout
000e8da0 B std::cout
000e9020 B std::wcout
```

Where is the link to the actual function and what does the B mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means the symbol is global and in the uninitialized data section (historically named BSS hence the 'B').   More nm info here:

http://linux.die.net/man/1/nm

Also likely available if you type "man 1 nm".

And what about the function?  Well, "cout" is an object instance, not a function.  Its class will have functions, mostly operator overloads in this particular case.

Comment: So is cout << "whatever" being instantiated as a std::cout object and then calling the std::operator<< to print it?

Comment: std::cout is probably being a global object, and thus placed in the global(bss) secion. Somewhere before your programs 'main' is called there platform will run a consttructor and initialize std::cout (and other globals).

Answer (score 1):

From the nm manual page:

> ```
>    B       The symbol is in the uninitialized data section (known as BSS).
> ```

Answer (score 1):

"Uninitialized" data, the BSS section, is actually initialized by the OS loader to all-zeros. It doesn't take up space in the image on disk, since the content is known to be all-zeros - just the size is stored in the image.

Global variables are normally allocated in the BSS section. This is also the reason that global variables are generally zero-initialized.